# Read .continuous file from open ephys using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of .continuous files containing EEG data from Openephys. I am trying to read the information in order to recover the time-series to analyze them using Python tools. However, every recommended library I tried returned a similar error; for example: using `pyopenephys` (`continuous_data = pyopenephys.File(continuous_file)`), I get the error `NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory`; when I use the MNE library, I get the same error; when using h5py, I get `OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)`. How can I read the data from the .continuous file into Python code?

Comment: The ones that error with `NotADirectoryError` probably want the directory the files are in, not a file itself. [The pyopenephys docs say as much](https://pypi.org/project/pyopenephys/).

Comment: [pyopenephys](https://github.com/CINPLA/pyopenephys) describe a python file read example.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. The path to the file is ```/home/usuario/Downloads/files/```. When I tried ```file = pyopenephys.File("/home/usuario/Downloads/files/") ```, it returned the error ```Exception: Only 'binary' and 'openephys' format are supported by pyopenephys
```; when I tried including the file, i.e., ```file = pyopenephys.File("/home/usuario/Downloads/files/100_1.continuous") ```, I get the error ```NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/usuario/Downloads/files/100_1.continuous' ```. So, I really didn't understand how this library works.

Answer (score 0):

The directory that you need is a directory with the file that has a date. Open ephys create a directory each time that you done a record and these directory is named with a date and time.
example: `file=pyopenephys.File("2024-01-25_11-27-13")`